# LinearLayout doesn't fit

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have this activity in my application:

[image: Image1]

I can't set the second CardView correctly. I need to use all free space between the card and the buttons at the end
 I tried everything, match_parent, alignment... but nothing.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:id="@+id/left_drawer_activity_customers_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer_activity_customers_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo_sfumato"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

            android:id="@+id/appbar_activity_customers_details">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_customers_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scrollDetails"
            >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
                >

                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/title_customers_details"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/title_customers_details"
                        android:id="@+id/customersdetails_nome"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_nome"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/customersdetails_città"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_città"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/customersdetails_indirizzo"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_indirizzo"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/customersdetails_provincia"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_provincia"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/customersdetails_phone"
                        android:autoLink="phone"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Fragment Container -->
            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/fragment_container"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--&gt;-->

            <!--</LinearLayout>-->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Apri ticket"
                android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
                >

                <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="12dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/test"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/test"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ticket"
                    android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Contratti"
                    android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right_activity_customers_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right_customer"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_right_customer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_left_activity_customers_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_left_drawer" />
```

Do I need to insert all my layout in another linear_layout?

Can someone help me please?

**Edit**
I used 200dp in layout_height just for take the screenshot

Comment: I use 200 dp just to take the screenshot, I didn't write it, excuse me

Comment: Do you want to the cardview to take the remainder of the space, or the parent `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @aandis yes, I've edited my question

Comment: There are 2 scrollviews in your layout. The first one doesn't seem to be required if you need the scroll only to work on the 2nd scroll view section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `ScrollView` with id `scrollDetails` from your layout.
2. Wrap the `CardView` & `LinearLayout` holding those 3 buttons at bottom into a `RelativeLayout` like below.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">


           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:layout_above="@+id/linearButtonLayout"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
               card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
               card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
               card_view:cardElevation="7dp">

               <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                   <RelativeLayout
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:padding="12dp" >

                       <TextView
                           android:id="@+id/test"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="@string/big_string"/>

                   </RelativeLayout>

               </ScrollView>

           </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/linearButtonLayout"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:gravity="center|bottom">

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button1"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="Ticket"
                   android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button2"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="Contratti"
                   android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button3"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="Contatti"
                   android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

           </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: I've got problems when user change the orientation of the screen using this way, you too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

Assign top LinearLayout (after ScrollView one) a wieghtSum 10 and then assign first cardView a layout_wieght = 3 and to button below it a layout_wieght = 1 and cardView below it a layout_wieght = 4 and LinearLayout below a layout_wieght = 2 .

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_customers_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customersdetails_nome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_customers_details"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customersdetails_città"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_nome"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customersdetails_indirizzo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_città"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customersdetails_provincia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_indirizzo"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customersdetails_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/customersdetails_provincia"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
    android:text="Apri ticket"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test" />
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        android:text="Ticket"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        android:text="Contratti"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        android:text="Contatti"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using this way I don't have the scrollview into the card but I can scroll all the activity, how to scroll only text inside the card?

Comment: Change the ScrollView height to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to keep all of your scrolling, Change in your second CardView  layout_height to 0dp and add layout_weight like below:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Change your bottom LinearLayout height to wrap_content like this

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I hope your problem is solved.